# VBA Check if records exist if not Append

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have two queries which concatenate the values in their respective tables (tbl1 & tb2). If there is no match, then an append query runs with the use of a Macro. 
The problem I'm having is figuring out the correct syntax in VBA (as I'd like to use my own warning messages rather than the standard Access ones).

I've converted the Macro to VBA and i'm currently using the code below:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
MsgBox "Append Successful", vbOKCancel, "Append"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "appendQuery"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

The main issue is that I still get the same message regardless if the Append is successful or not. Is there a way to say something like:

```
If 'concat1' matches 'concat2' 
MsgBox "Record already exists. Append not executed"
Else run 'appendQuery'
MsgBox "Append Successful"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this with vanilla Access is to actually go from a completely different direction. Do an Update query first, based on the filter criteria for the Insert (append) query, and if db.RecordsAffected is 0 then the record does not exist, and you can insert.

```
set db = CurrentDb
'we don't actually care about changing things, just want to see if the record exists 
db.Execute("UPDATE sometable SET somevalue = somevalue WHERE ID = 1234")
If db.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
    'id doesn't exist
    db.Execute("INSERT INTO sometable (id,somevalue) VALUES (1234,'MyValue')")
Else
    'id exists, handle the fact that it exists
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

The query looks a little strange, but should do exactly what you're looking for:

```
  Dim db as DAO.Database
  Dim SQL as string

  SQL = "INSERT INTO blah (id, somevalue) " & _
        "SELECT TOP 1 1, 'somevalue' FROM blah " & _
        "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM blah WHERE id=1 AND somevalue='somevalue');"

  set db = currentdb
  db.execute SQL
  if db.RecordsAffected = 0 then
    msgbox "Record already exists; append not executed."
  else
    msgbox "Record appended successfully."
  end if
```

Comment: Be careful here.  That `INSERT` will attempt to add as many rows as are returned by the `SELECT` piece.  Without unique constraints, they will get added.

Comment: @HansUp raises a good point. I was assuming the `id` field is a primary key constraint. Updated the query to eliminate the problem.